# Regex remove new lines within speech marks - Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've got a load of SVG files generated by Illustrator, that I need to add classes and stuff to.

Illustrator has wrapped most of the lines with line brakes like this (below). All of them within the d attribute, but sometimes 2 or 3 lines.

```
<path stroke-width="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"  d="M180.352,278.306c0.379,8.944,0.743,17.749,1.098,26.44
        L70.842,415.35c0.33-9.5,0.661-18.997,0.999-28.533L180.352,278.306z" class="G"/>
```

Working with it like this is getting quite annoying, and as I suck at regex I was hoping someone would be able to help me with this.

Basically I want it to be laid out with one path tag per line.

I'm not great at explaining things, so let me know if this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for this pattern:

```
("[^"]*)\n(?=[^"]*")
```

And replace with:

```
$1
```

Before:
[image: Heading]

After:
[image: After]